# Confused about setting up parameters for an SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, orm, dapper

I'm using Dapper ORM to query my database. I've familiarized myself with the query syntax, but I'm having issues with the parameters.

Here is the query that works:

```
orders = ctx.Query<OrderView>(myQuery, new { Seller = 104386, StatusID = 2, query = "people"});
```

This maps the parameters in myQuery (@Seller, @StatusID, @query) to these values and it works correctly.

However, in my program, I generate parameters on the fly and store them in an `List<ObjectParameter>`, so each parameter has a name and a value. However, I can't get this to work correctly in the query. Here is an example of what doesn't work:

```
orders = ctx.Query<OrderView>(myQuery, parameters.toArray());
```

I've also tried converting that to `List<SqlParameter>` but that doesn't work either. Does anyone know how I can replicate the working query with my parameters list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectParameter` is an EF thing (`System.Data.Entity.dll`) and is not used in dapper. You want `DynamicParameters`, inside the dapper assembly / namespace:

```
var args = new DynamicParameters();
...
args.Add(name, value); // there are more complex usages, note
...
connection.Query<OrderView>(myQuery, args);
```

If you want to take more control - for example you *really* want to use `ObjectParameter` - that's fine too: you just write your own type that implements `SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters`, and pass that to dapper.